# segmentation fault pushback an object created inside loop of its class function c++

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

i m trying to create and insert into vector inside a for loop but i m getting segmentation fault i know why and i know the reason but what i m asking is how can i prevent it , 
i m getting error because end of the scope created object dies....

```
void Board::Resize()
{
    for(int i=0; i<Row_Size; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<Column_Size; j++)
        {
            Cell copyCell(i,static_cast<char>('a'+j),'.');

            BoardCells[i].push_back(copyCell);
        }
    }
}
```

Board class has a vector of vector of Cells in private

```
vector<vector Cell> myCells;
```

and Cell class have in private

```
int row;
char column;
char status;
```

its a smiple class not much variables

if i cant use pushback like this than how can i do ? (filling with objects inside vector without segmantation fault )

Comment: Where to you resize the outer vector - BoardCells? You are accessing `BoardCells[i]` as if it already exists but show no code that adds it to the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Do you clear `myCells` before calling `Resize()`? You probably want to add a new row per each value of `i` (via that very `push_back()`) and then add new cells to it.

Comment: BoardCells.clear(); 

yes i clear  BoardCells  actually inside Resize function

Comment: So definitely `BoardCells[i]` is out of bounds. First you need to add it in the outer loop, before looping the inner one, so that you have the row to populate. If you do so, you can use `BoardCells.back()` in the inner loop to refer to the i'th row. :)

Comment: yes!! that is definetly the problem i m trying to  get inside of vector that has no vector  
so i tried this but also error i m not so good  with syntax , is this right ? BoardCells[i].reserve(sizeof(int)*Row_Size);

Comment: No.

First, you add a line `BoardCells.push_back(vector<Cell>())` in the outer loop, before the inner one. Then you can add cells to the newly created row.

Comment: Thank you so much ! i though i had to reserve